# Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined

Tags: feature-request, flags, declined-flags, flag-ban

When someone gets a declined flag, they get the following message when they try to flag another post:

> Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please review them before flagging this post!

This messages means that my last flag wasn't helpful and that I'm not paying enough attention when flagging posts. 
So, why did I get that warning because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27525874/1638739)? When reading the question, you will find that it's well-formatted and asked according to standards, but it wasn't like that when I flagged it. It was just the following:

> I have to do an application that shows an image of the medication packages. I've found this site that have some, but I'm trying to download the available images with a little program in Java but fails. I think HTTPS causes the issue.
>
> There's a way to do it?

So, I flagged it as "*unclear what you're asking*", and I think it was then a helpful flag. But the OP edited it and added the required code. So, it's a well-formatted question now and my flag got declined. I think it's not fair to judge my flag after the post was edited, and I think SO has to consider this problem and look for the flag timing.

Comment: That did not need flagging; it just needed a vote to close ("unclear what you're asking", since there's no code).  A down vote might also be in order.  A comment to help the user if they're new would be kind.  It does not need a moderator's precious time. The community can deal with that quite easily.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler not everyone can close vote. That's sort of the point of flags. I don't believe "unclear what you're asking" even goes to the moderators.

Comment: What I'd like is a way to appeal from the moderator's decision.

Comment: @matt that will be great, but how ?

Comment: @eddie_cat *"I don't believe "unclear what you're asking" even goes to the moderators."* Correct. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203216/who-reviews-my-flags-and-suggestions

Comment: The flag really should've been marked as *disputed*, as the OP obviously took your comment into account and edited their question.

Comment: @cybermonkey that would be fair enough

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yeah it sucks when things get changed *after* you flag. However, the review process doesn't allow for that scenario. Users are only presented with the option to Close, Edit, or Leave Open. They don't even know they'd be handling a flag by reviewing it. If it shouldn't be closed, naturally they would choose to leave it open, which is what happened and is why your flag got declined. Moderators cannot manually dismiss these flags and there's no criteria from review that would let users indicate that a previous revision *should have been closed* but not the current revision.

On the bright side - it's just *one* flag. It's not going to affect you in the long-run. You reviewed it, evaluated the situation, determined the flag status was wrong, and concluded that there's nothing to learn from it. So just ignore it and move on.

Comment: Would it not be possible to have the review process reset once an edit has occurred and those flags that had been raised prior to the edit classified as "outdated" or something similar?

Comment: @rozkosz I don't think that would necessarily be a good idea, as someone could edit their question repeatedly to keep it from being closed because of flags. I do think a flag that was declined after an edit was posted could be marked as `outdated`, `disputed`, or `corrected`. Or! `deprecated`

Comment: @Tom You are right that gaming the system would be an issue if the review process were restarted with every edit, but your idea of marking flags that were declined after an edit as `deprecated` is brilliant!