# Can we get a notification when a flag is declined?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, declined-flags, notifications

Some time ago I stumbled upon a strange activity: a person [deliberately added irrelevant tags to posts with their own answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3704489/star?tab=activity) under a clumsy pretext "I faced the same issue using [such platform]" while the issue being totally irrelevant to the platform. As I make it, they wanted to make themselves a name in this particular tag, probably to show a potential employer.

Either way, adding irrelevant tags is destructive. So I reported this account and moved on. Today I just noticed the flag was declined. If there would have been a notification, I would have contested it but there was none.

So can we get a notification? Or some other communication channel with moderators, as I am feeling that writing a whole post on Meta for the purpose is sort of overkill.

Comment: And what would you do if you received such a notification? 1:1 communications between 18 moderators and 12 million of us isn't really going to work very well.

Comment: @RobertLongson Be aware of it. It could be nice to get a notice in the inbox, instead of going though the flag-list and sort through all the declined ones to find out if a flag raised weeks ago was declined or not.

Comment: Flags are mostly supposed to be fire and forget. Decline notifications would only serve for more users coming to meta to complain about their flags not being honored. Noise, much more often than not. There is no need to “be aware” of declines unless they become a pattern, and by then you will get be warned if you try to flag again.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of, definitely a subset of, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284688/notify-me-when-my-flag-has-been-handled

Comment: Why people downvoting this, I thought we all agreed that decline notifications was something we wanted?

Comment: @yivi I disagree. Decline notifications can serve as a learning opportunity. Declined flags usually come with a message (although not a custom one) stating the reason anyway so why not present that to the user? If (some) users go and post on Meta to complain, let the community moderate those posts. I doubt that it would happen often anyway since the reason for the decline is already mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So can we get a notification? Or some other communication channel with moderators, as I am feeling that writing a whole post on Meta for the purpose is sort of overkill.

Discussion over declined flags *can* be overkill generally on the Stack Overflow, as the moderator flag queue is huge. Unless a moderator has made a mistake (which sometimes happens) having to reiterate why the flag is declined or debate it, is time consuming and not practical.

If you feel the flag was wrongly declined, raise another flag on another post and the mods will usually respond with a custom message if they decline it, or post on meta. That is the least time consuming option for moderators, as it also allows the community to weigh in and answer more obvious flag declines.

So in summary, notifying people that their flags have been declined is only going to draw more attention to this and create more work for moderators. If people are really concerned about a user, as in your case, keeping track of your flag history is a simpler and viable way to deal with this, as most flag outcomes do not need to be micromanaged.

If people get declined flag*s*, they already get a [notification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281081/attention-some-of-your-recent-flags-have-been-declined) when they next flag asking them to review their recent flags or a [temporary flag ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283396/why-am-i-banned-after-a-single-helpful-flag-after-flag-ban).

Comment: _"If people get declined flags, they already get a notification when they next flag"_ Oh okay, thank you! I didn't know that was the case. I think that's good enough.